# How can I get ids of nested created records in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, activemodel

I have a record with `accepts_nested_attributes_for` and after creation I want to get the ids and attributes of the created records **without making another query**. Is it possible?

For example, I have this record:

```rb
class Product
  has_many :variants
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :variants
end
```

Then I can do:

```rb
product = Product.create!(name: 'test_product', variants_attributes: [{ name: 'test_variant' }])
```

But if I call `product.variants` it does another query to the database.

Comment: I don't like `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, it's not friendly to understand and hard to use. forget it, and use another approach

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't your class be like this:

```
class Product
  has_many :variants
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :variants
end
```

I am not sure how your code is working without properly defining the `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. `product.variants` command should not fire another query if you have saved the created object in the variable `product`.

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo defining `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, I've just edited it. And `product.variants` does fire another query, just try it out the way I explained in my question.